# Using pandas series date as xtick label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have this dataframe called 'dfArrivalDate' (with the first 11 rows shown)

```
arrival_date  count
0    2013-06-08      9
1    2013-06-27      8
2    2013-03-06      8
3    2013-06-01      8
4    2013-06-28      6
5    2012-11-28      6
6    2013-06-11      5
7    2013-06-29      5
8    2013-06-09      4
9    2013-06-03      3
10   2013-05-31      3

sortedArrivalDate = transform.sort('arrival_date')
```

I wanted to plot them in a bar chart to see the count by arrival date. I called

```
sortedArrivalDate.plot(kind = 'bar') [![enter image description here][1]]
```

but i'm getting the index as the row ticks of my bar chart. I figured i need to use 'xticks'.

```
sortedArrivalDate.plot(kind = 'bar', xticks = sortedArrivalDate.arrival_date)
```

but I run into the error: TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'float'

I tried a different approach.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(sortedArrivalDate.arrival_date, sortedArrivalDate.count)
```

This time the error is ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension

I'm thinking this might just be an easy fix and since I don't have much experience coding in pandas and matplotlib, I might be missing a very simple thing here. Care to guide me in the right direction? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df = df.sort_values(by='arrival_date')
df.plot(x='arrival_date', y='count', kind='bar')
```

[image]